# How did the asura Chalantarana die?

Tags: shiva, death, asuras

Chalantarana was a very powerful and very famous asura, and it well known how he was born (from the energy and rage in Lord Siva's eyes when Indra sent a bolt towards him).

But I do not know the story of his death, although I heard that he was killed by Siva as well. Can anyone tell me who killed him and how he died?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This story is in the Shiva Purana, and you are correct that Chalantarana was killed by Shiva. ('Chalantarana' is a variant spelling of the original name 'Jalandhara') There is a chapter devoted to the entire battle scene, although I've only provided the lines that describe the death itself. From [Shiva Purana, Rudrasamhita, Chapter 24:](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226165.html)

> 45. Śiva held in his hand the wheel Sudarśana which he had made with his toe and got ready to kill him.
> 46. Lord Śiva hurled the discus Sudarśana which resembled a crore suns and the fire of dissolution.
> 47. Blazing the heaven and the earth, the discus hit Jalandhara and severed his head with wide gaping eyes.
> 48. The body of the son of the ocean fell on the ground from the chariot making the earth resonant. The head too fell. There was a great hue and cry.
> 49. His body fell in two halves like the mountain of collyrium split by the thunderbolt and hurled in the ocean.
> 50. The whole universe was filled with his terrible blood O great sage, the entire earth became deformed.
> 51. His entire blood and flesh, at the bidding of Śiva was taken to the hell Mahāraurava[5] and became a big pit of blood there.

In case you are interested, here are the same lines from the [original Sanskrit version](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit/d/doc377678.html):

> sudarśanākhyaṃ yaccakraṃ padāṃguṣṭhavinirmitam |
> jagrāha tatkare rudrastena haṃtuṃ samudyataḥ || 45 ||
>
> sudarśanākhyaṃ taccakraṃ cikṣepa bhagavānharaḥ |
> koṭisūryapratīkāśaṃ pralayānalasannibham || 46 ||
>
> pradahadrodasī vegāttadāsādya jalaṃdharam |
> jahāra tacchiro vegānmahadāyatalocanam || 47 ||
>
> rathātkāyaḥ papātorvyāṃ nādayanvasudhātalam |
> śiraścāpyabdhiputrasya hāhākāro mahānabhūt || 48 ||
>
> dvidhā papāta taddeho hyaṃjanādririvācalaḥ |
> kuliśena yathā vārāṃnidhau girivaro dvidhā || 49 ||
>
> tasya raudreṇa raktena sampūrṇamabhavajjagat |
> tatassamastā pṛthivī vikṛtābhūnmunīśvara || 50 ||
>
> tadraktamakhilaṃ rudraniyogānmāṃsameva ca |
> mahārauravamāsādya raktakuṃḍamabhūdiha || 51 ||